# Why does referencing my large array crash my program?

Tags: c, reference

When i run my program it just crashes I have been looking for a answer for about a day and can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int s=10000;
    int i,j,temp;
    int matrix[s][s];
    
    clock_t start, end;
    int cpu_time_used;
    start=clock();
    
    for(i=1; i<s; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<s; j++)
        {   
            matrix[s][s];
        }
    }
    
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used= ((int)(end-start));
    printf("Total Time Used for Subscripting: %d\n",cpu_time_used);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `matrix[i][j];` instead of `matrix[s][s];`, and you should use zero indexing to avoid out-of-bound.

Comment: Assuming a 32bit `int`, that array encompasses over 380 MB of automatic storage. *Don't do that*. Either make it dynamic or move it into static storage.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not sure static would be a good idea either. Dynamic is the only reasonable thing to do.

Comment: If `s` is going to be _fixed_, you can [at global scope] do: `#define s 10000` and then: `int matrix[s][s];`

Comment: @klutt That might be a bit advanced at OP's current skill level since it involves pointer to array syntax to maintain the 2D indexing.

Comment: Side note: you loops do nothing. It is likely that the compiler will optimise it and remove everything.

Comment: Please read [ask]. "it just crashes" is not a good problem statement. Is throwing a segfault? If so, where? Have you tried stepping into it in the debugger?

Comment: BTW: Arrays in C start at index 0 and end at, in your case, `s-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Given an array:

```
int a[N];
```

The extent of `a` is `a[0]..a[N-1]`.

So in your case, the maximum legal index values for `matrix[s][s]` are `[s-1][s-1]`.

Another possible issue is the shear size of the local storage, due to `s==10000`, you have an array in local storage that is `10000^2*sizeof(int)`, which is probably larger than the stack you have configured for your process.